# Craft 3 Docs Group Filter Not Working

Tags: templating, craft3, filter

I am attempting to replicate the example from https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/templating/filters.html#group

However, I am unable to access the `{{ year }}` in the first for loop inside the h2 element. It just shows up as an empty string. Anyone have an idea whats going on?

Here is my code:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('weeklyDigests').all() %}
{% set allEntriesByYear = allEntries|group('postDate.year') %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allEntriesByYear %}
   <h2>{{ year }}</h2>

   <ul>

   {% for entry in entriesInYear %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}

   </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!  In Craft 3, `postDate` is a full PHP [DateTime object](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), so it'd need to be something like:

```
{% set allEntriesByYear = allEntries|group('postDate|date("Y")') %}
```